# Read all txt files and assign a symbolic link for each one

Tags: bash, for-loop

I would like to assign a symbolic link for each text files from the same folder.
Be more specific, let's say there are four text files in a folder.

```
AAAA.txt
BBBB.txt
ABAB.txt
BABA.txt
```

I would like to assign a symbolic link for each. For example

```
ln -s AAAA.txt sample1.txt
ln -s BBBB.txt sample2.txt
ln -s ABAB.txt sample3.txt
ln -s BABA.txt sample4.txt
```

How can I use forloop to do this?

```
for f in "$dir"/.txt; 
do
ln -s $f sample[1,2,3,4].txt (I know this is not right !!!)
done
```

Comment: You are right, the way of using `[1,2,3,4]` would _never_ work in `bash` as it is not a valid construct at all. Perhaps you were trying to use brace expansion? `{1..4}` even then in your case it would have expanded to `ln -s $f sample1.txt sample2.txt sample3.txt sample4.txt` which is quite incorrect as per the given requirement

Comment: You can do it without a `for` loop by the way, with **GNU Parallel** like this `parallel ln -s {} sample{#}.txt ::: *txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
i=1;
for f in "$dir"/*.txt; 
do
    ln -s "$f" "sample{$i}.txt";
    ((i+=1));
done
```

Comment: Doesn't the `for f in "$dir"/.txt; ` need a `*` ?